Brauer Tables for the Monster Group
I am doing research on modular character theory and wanted to study the Brauer Table for some of the larger simple groups, however I have been struggling to find the Brauer Tables for the monster group. Does anyone know of any resources where I could find the Brauer Tables for the Monster group?

Hello and welcome to Math.SE. Please take a look at How to ask a good question. and edit your question, since your question does not meet the standards on Math.SE. The biggest problems are: there is no context, it is not clear why you are asking and your work is not visible. See also the Code of Conduct.

What is a Brauer table ? Do you mean the character table ?

It is similar to the character table, but it deals with modular characters. It is a field of character theory but the field we work in is now characteristic p, rather than 0.

I think that there are no primes for which the Brauer characters of the Monster are known. Some are known for all primes, but not all for any prime. See the book by Hiss and Lux, Brauer Trees for Sporadic Groups, for more.

@DavidA.Craven: Don't we know the ordinary character table of the Monster, and thus the Brauer character table for every prime $p$ not dividing the order of the Monster?

@testaccount The Brauer character tables cannot be deduced from the ordinary character table, or at least we know of no such way.

@DavidA.Craven: I must be missing something - if $\chi$ is an ordinary character (over $\mathbb{C}$), isn't its restriction $\hat{\chi}$ to the set of $p'$-elements a Brauer character? And this defines a bijection between $Irr(G)$ and $IBr(G)$ if $p \nmid |G|$, by Theorem 15.13 in Isaacs' character theory book?

@testaccount Sorry, I misread what you wrote. If $p\nmid |G|$ then the Brauer character table is the ordinary character table. They are identical. So when we talk about Brauer character tables we almost exclusively refer to the case where $p\mid |G|$.
